# Meteor Deps.Autorun know when data has been fully fetched

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to know when data has been initially fully fetched from the server after running Deps.autorun for the first time?

For example:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
    var data = ItemsCollection.find().fetch();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Initially my console log will show `Object { items=[0] }` as the data has not yet been fetched from the server. I can handle this first run.

However, the issue is that the function will be rerun whenever data is received which may not be when the full collection has been loaded. For example, I sometimes received `Object { items=[12] }` quickly followed by `Object { items=[13] }` (which isn't due to another client changing data).

So - is there a way to know when a full load has taken place for a certain dependent function and all collections within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor.subscribe returns a handle with a reactive ready method, which is set to true when "an initial, complete snapshot of the record set has been sent" (see http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_ready)

Using this information you can design something simple such as :

```
var waitList=[Meteor.subscribe("firstSub"),Meteor.subscribe("secondSub"),...];

Deps.autorun(function(){
  // http://underscorejs.org/#every
  var waitListReady=_.every(waitList,function(handle){
    return handle.ready();
  });
  if(waitListReady){
    console.log("Every documents sent in publications is now available.");
  }
});
```

Unless you're prototyping a toy project, this is not a solid design and you probably want to use iron-router (http://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router) which provides great design patterns to address this kind of problems.

In particular, take a moment and have a look at these 3 videos from the main iron-router contributor :

https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/waiting-on-subscriptions

https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/the-reactive-waitlist-data-structure

https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/using-wait-waiton-and-ready-in-routes

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the subscription handle somewhere and then use the `ready` method to determine whether the initial data load has been completed.

So if you subscribe to the collection using:

```
itemSub = Meteor.subscribe('itemcollections', blah blah...)
```

You can then surround your `find` and `console.log` statements with:

```
if (itemSub.ready()) { ... }
```

and they will only be executed once the initial dataset has been received.

Note that there are *possible* ocassions when the collection handle will return `ready` marginally before some of the items are received if the collection is large and you are dealing with significant latency, but the problem should be very minor. For more on why and how the `ready ()` method actually works, see [this](http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-low-level-publications/).